# What are the products when KCl and H2SO4 reacts?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have been trying to find the right answer by googling and I just ended up finding multiple answers.

Ans #1: $\ce{2KCl + H2SO4 -> K2SO4 + 2HCl}$

Ans #2: $\ce{KCl + H2SO4 -> KHSO4 + HCl}$

Can someone help me?

Comment: Both of these are correct. It depends on how much KCl you add to the H2SO4.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction between $\ce{KCl}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$ depends from the temperature, and of the presence of water.

First both reactions need a total absence of water. In the presence of water, no $\ce{HCl}$ is liberated.

Second at room temperature, the reaction happens only at the surface of $\ce{KCl}$. So it is inefficient, because the product of the reaction prevents some further contact between $\ce{H2SO4}$ and the rest of  $\ce{KCl}$. If the temperature is near $210°C$ (melting point of $\ce{KHSO4}$), the reaction $(2)$ is efficient and produces $\ce{KHSO4 + HCl}$, as $\ce{KHSO4}$ is a liquid, and the reaction can proceed fast.

The first reaction must be made in two steps. First the mixture $\ce{KCl + H2SO4}$ must be heated at $210°C$, and then, when the first $\ce{HCl}$ is finished, $\ce{KHSO4}$ and $\ce{KCl}$ can be overheated at a higher temperature, near $1000°C$. And only then will $\ce{K2SO4 + HCl}$ be produced according to $(1)$.

In summary, the reaction $(1)$ is the sum of ($2)$ (occurring at ~$210°C$) plus the following reaction, happening at ~$1000°C$ :
$$\ce{KHSO4 + KCl -> K2SO4 + HCl}$$